# DOM created table but not all columns have cells

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-table

I am making a website that you can type in. I am working on the tables. Only one column has a cell. all others are blank. what do I do?

Code:

```js
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
var row = 10;
var col = 10;
row += 1;
col += 1;
var headingChild = document.createElement("table");
var headingParent = document.getElementsByClassName("editable")[0];
headingParent.appendChild(headingChild);
while (i < row) {
  var rowParent = headingChild.insertRow(-1);

  while (j < col) {
    var cellParent = rowParent.insertCell(-1);
    cellParent.style = "border: solid;";
    j++;



  }
  i++;
}
```

```css
td {
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" class="editable">
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset `j` back to `0` for each row. The minimal change is:

```js
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
var row = 10;
var col = 10;
row += 1;
col += 1;
var headingChild = document.createElement("table");
var headingParent = document.getElementsByClassName("editable")[0];
headingParent.appendChild(headingChild);
while (i < row) {
  var rowParent = headingChild.insertRow(-1);

  j = 0; // <=========================================== here
  while (j < col) {
    var cellParent = rowParent.insertCell(-1);
    cellParent.style = "border: solid;";
    j++;
  }
  i++;
}
```

```css
td {
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" class="editable">
```

...but really, this is a job for `for` loops:

```js
// *** Removed i and j here
var row = 10;
var col = 10;
row += 1;
col += 1;
var headingChild = document.createElement("table");
var headingParent = document.getElementsByClassName("editable")[0];
headingParent.appendChild(headingChild);
for (var i = 0; i < row; ++i) {                   // ***
  var rowParent = headingChild.insertRow(-1);

  for (var j = 0; j < col; ++j) {                 // ***
    var cellParent = rowParent.insertCell(-1);
    cellParent.style = "border: solid;";
    // *** Removed j++;
  }
  // *** Removed i++;
}
```

```css
td {
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" class="editable">
```

Comment: how do I make it a square and not a line?

Comment: @EthanZoneCoding - Remove the CSS that's overriding the default handling of table cells.